# svg circle showing as square

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to use an svg to make a pie chart so I found this [codepen](https://codepen.io/rvmook/pen/LNLGoE) that has an animated pie chart

I am trying to make that pie chart 20 x 20 instead of 50 x 50 so I thought I could just change the width and height and then half that for the radius, and center points.

I also changed the stroke width in the css to 20 and the circumference to 63 (2 x pie x 10) so I am not sure what else I need to change to make the square back into a circle.

However, I get a weird bug in that the pie piece turns into a square: [click on the 100% button](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/prwXyM).

Is there anyway to make that second circle into a circle again?

I have included the following snippet but it doesn't allow for scss so I could not get it to replicate the pen, but it demonstrates the square issue.

```css
body {
  /* Appearance */
  background-color: #2c333b;
}

a, h5, h3 {
  /* Display & Box Model */
  margin: 10px 0;
  /* Text */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  /* Appearance */
  color: #fff;
}

.svg {
  /* Appearance */
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle {
  /* Appearance */
  fill: #fdded9;
}

#pie {
  /* Appearance */
  stroke: #ff4081;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 63;
  stroke-width: 20;
  transition: stroke-dasharray .2s linear;
}
#pie.percent-10 {
  stroke-dasharray: 6.3 63;
}
#pie.percent-20 {
  stroke-dasharray: 12.6 63;
}
#pie.percent-30 {
  stroke-dasharray: 18.9 63;
}
#pie.percent-40 {
  stroke-dasharray: 25.2 63;
}
#pie.percent-50 {
  stroke-dasharray: 31.5 63;
}
#pie.percent-60 {
  stroke-dasharray: 37.8 63;
}
#pie.percent-70 {
  stroke-dasharray: 44.1 63;
}
#pie.percent-80 {
  stroke-dasharray: 50.4 63;
}
#pie.percent-90 {
  stroke-dasharray: 56.7 63;
}
#pie.percent-100 {
  stroke-dasharray: 63 63;
}

.wrapper {
  /* Positioning */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* Display & Box Model */
  width: 100px;
  /* Appearance */
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <svg width="20" height="20" class="svg">
  <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" class="circle"/>
  <circle id="pie" r="10" cx="10" cy="10" class="circle percent-100"/>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: it is about size and coordonates : `<svg width="100" height="100" class="svg">
  <circle r="20" cx="30" cy="30" class="circle"/>
  <circle id="pie" r="10" cx="20" cy="20" class="circle percent-100"/>
 </svg>` shows the circles, not just a part of it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things:

1. The inner circle should have radius of 5 (not 10)
2. The `$circumference` in your CSS should be the one for the inner circle (which has radius of 5,) so it should be 31.4
3. The `stroke-width` should be the side of the 10 (size of the outer cirlce, and not 20)

Here is the fix:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLwjdb

> Note that I also changed the value of the `CIRCUMFERENCE` in your js code, but it only affect the `onButtonClickDynamic` function which you never call, but it's there in case you will need it.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can circle name of the SVG in

```
svg circle{
.....
}
```

and svg circle html sytax is wrong,it should be:

```
<circle r="20" cx="30" cy="30" class="circle"></circle>
```